# rails-4 not getting all columns from 2 tables with join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This is my model.rb

model.rb

```
class Compute
belongs_to :user
end

class User
has_many :computes
end
```

I have used this query to get all details

```
User.joins(:computes).where.not(skey: 'NULL')
```

and i got all from USER table,also i need to get one or more column
from COMPUTE with USER.

Comment: User.where.not(skey: 'NULL').joins(:computes).collect{|usr| usr.computes.map{|po|po.attributes.merge(usr.attributes)}}.....
is it correct solution?, is there any simple method?

Comment: When using joins you have to mention the column names to select.eg
`User.joins(:computes).where.not(skey: 'NULL').select("users.name, computes.name")`

Comment: Use include instead.`User.includes(:computes).where.not(skey: 'NULL')`

Comment: You should add `SELECT` statement in query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this

```
User.joins(:computes).where.not(skey: 'NULL').select("users.id, computes.name")
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.select` use `.pluck`. Like

```
Table_1.joins(:table_2).where(:conditions).pluck('table_1.col_1', 'table_1.col_2', 'table_2.col_1', 'table_2.col_2')
```

---

```
User.joins(:computes).where.not(skey: 'NULL').pluck('users.id', 'computes.name')
```